# Copying and merging column values when condition met in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am kinda new to pandas and am struggling to find a solution to my problem.

My dataframe looks something like this :

| Id | num | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.5 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 30 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3.6 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 11 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

When the value from the column "Id" is the same, I want to copy the value from the "num" column to the column that has "1" as a value in column A, B or C and then merge them into one row and remove "num" column completely.

Kinda like this :

| Id | num | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.5 | 0 | 0 | 3.5 |
| 1 | 10 | 0 | 10 | 0 |
| 1 | 30 | 30 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3.6 | 0 | 0 | 3.6 |
| 2 | 11 | 0 | 11 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 20 | 0 | 0 |

And finally :

| Id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 10 | 3.5 |
| 2 | 20 | 11 | 3.6 |

Comment: Do you need merge all columns without `Id` and `num` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, this is a simple multiplication, use `mul`:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df['num'], axis=0)
```

Second step, use `groupby`+`max`:

```
df.groupby('Id', as_index=False)[cols].max()
```

All steps without intermediate:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
(df[cols].mul(df['num'], axis=0)
         .groupby(df['Id']).max()
         .reset_index()
)
```

Output 1:

```
   Id   num     A     B    C
0   1   3.5   0.0   0.0  3.5
1   1  10.0   0.0  10.0  0.0
2   1  30.0  30.0   0.0  0.0
3   2   3.6   0.0   0.0  3.6
4   2  11.0   0.0  11.0  0.0
5   2  20.0  20.0   0.0  0.0
```

Output 2:

```
   Id     A     B    C
0   1  30.0  10.0  3.5
1   2  20.0  11.0  3.6
```